# How can we get battery level in Doubles in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to get battery level in doubles in flutter?? the battery package returns a int, but I want decimal accuracy in my app.

Comment: what's the use case of having battery level in decimal accuracy?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately that's not possible. On android the `BatteryManager` only has API for getting integer and on iOS platform you're getting battery level as double between 0 and 1 but with 2 decimal points accuracy which is not enough for your case.

Comment: Understood, and thank you for the response!